# C#: How to manipulate List<String> using LINQ or LAMBDA expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i'm having a `List<String>` like

```
 List<String> MyList=new List<String>
    {
    "101010",
    "000000",
    "111000"
    };
```

I need to create a new list (`List<String>`) with "MyList" . so the rows in the "MyList" becomes columns in the new List and the columns become rows

So the result will be like

```
 {
    "101",
    "001",
    "101",
    "000",
    "100",
    "000"
  }
```

now i'm using `nested for` loop to do this.

Is there any way to do this using `LINQ` or `LAMBDA` expression

Comment: What would you expect it to do if the strings weren't all the same length?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet : That scenerio won't occur. Because before adding data to the list i'll make them of same lenght( `PadLeft` function will be applied )

Comment: While you can surely do this using LINQ and lambda expressions, I seriously doubt that the result will be easier to read than your nested for loops. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var transposed = Enumerable.Range(0, MyList.First().Length)
                           .Select(rowIndex => new string(MyList.Select(str => str[rowIndex]).ToArray()))
                           .ToList();
```

Of course, this will break if the strings are not of identical length.

Comment: @ Ani : +1  `Enumerable.Range() ` should have two arguments (`.net 3.5`) .

Comment: Typo, sorry. I was 'manually copying' it by looking at the code I have written on an instance of VS I have open on another machine.

Comment: i think instead of `String.concat(...)` we have to use `new String(...)`

Comment: @Pramodh: That's a good idea, but `string.Concat` should work too.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) script that does the trick:

```
void Main()
{
    List<String> MyList = new List<String>
    {
        "101010",
        "000000",
        "111000"
    };
    Transpose(MyList).ToList().Dump();
}

static IEnumerable<String> Transpose(IEnumerable<String> strings)
{
    return from i in Enumerable.Range(0, strings.First().Length)
           select new string((from s in strings select s[i]).ToArray());
}
```

Output:

```
101
001
101
000
100
000
```

Comment: This has a poteniel problem, in that for some types of `IEnumerable<>s`, after the .First(), it will not reset to the beginning for the `from s in string`, so you'll miss the first row. In fact, you need it to reset every time, so you may be better off accepting a `List<>` as the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
        int n = myList[0].Length; // or whatever

        var transposed = from ind in Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                         let sb = new StringBuilder()
                         select myList.Select(s => s[ind]).Aggregate(sb, (acc, next) => acc.Append(next));

        foreach (var s in transposed)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```